# How to make a Discord bot create a new VC when joining a specific VC

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command which creates a voice channel with certain permissions and puts it under a category. Instead, I want the voice channel to be created when you join a specific voice channel called "Join to create" and you are moved to the new voice channel after it is created. I also want the new voice channel to automatically delete once everyone has left it.

I'm not quite sure how to do this so I'd really appreciate the help. Here is the code for the command:

```
  if (command === "createvc") {
    message.guild.channels.create(message.author.username + "'s Channel", {
    type: 'voice', parent: '703315964011479090',
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: message.guild.id, // everyone
          allow: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'STREAM', 'USE_VAD'],
          deny: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']
        },
        {
          id: '705036984934203473', // Muted
          allow: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          deny: ['CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'STREAM', 'USE_VAD', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']
        },
        {
          id: '705036553872998470', // Unverified
          deny: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'STREAM', 'USE_VAD', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']
        },
      ],
    })
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if someone joined the `Join to Create` channel using the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event and then creating a new voice channel using [`guild.channels.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) and then finally by moving the `GuildMember`(s) to that voice channel.

Your solution would be something like this:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (newState.channel.name === 'Join to Create') { // You can also use `newState.channelID`
        newState.guild.channels.create("New Channel", {
            type: 'voice',
            parent: 'CATEGORY_ID'
        }).then(vc => {
            newState.setChannel(vc);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Just one last thing, how would I make it so it deletes the new voice channel after all users have left it?

Comment: Now that, you need to store the VC somewhere then in 'voiceStateUpdate' do a loop through all the VCs you have stored and compare oldState.channelID with the stored VCs and delete it

Comment: Also please accept my answer to let others know that it worked

Comment: How would I write that?